# Defining a partial ordered set with a function

Tags: functions, order-theory

Is it possible to define a bivariate function $f$ which is merely a calculation (without trigo), and which enables to decide an order between the inputs? The inputs are in $\mathbb{N}$.

For instance, I would like to have

1) $f(a,b)<0$ if $a<b$,

2) $f(a,b)>0$ if $b<a$,

3) and $f(a,b)=0$ if $a=b$.

Thank you.

Comment: On which partially ordered set are your working?

Comment: Do you even know the definition of "well-order", that you've put this tag on your question?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I'm working on $\mathbb{N}$. Sorry for the bad tag.

Answer (score 1):

What about $f(a,b) = a-b$ ? $\ $